# how to write multiple sets of data to a file using isolatedstoragefile

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, isolatedstoragefile

I have a listbox in my windows phone app and its datatemplate has 4 textbox controls in it to represent question,answer,date and emailid.

when user saves this data I want to save them to local storage so that I can read it later for displaying the same data in app.
So how to write multiple sets of data to a file using isolatedstoragefile with each set of data containing the above data(question,answer,date and emailed) in each row.

And while reading each record how do I read each column (question,answer,date and emailid)differently ? I know we can concatenate them while writing and split them while reading each line.But I want to know if there is a way provided in IsolatedstorageFile api to read the way I wanted above.

Answer (score 0):

Just do like you would with a "normal" file.

I am not a big fan of a binary or XML serialization, so I would delimit the 4 fields with a semicolon and write each item (question;answer;date;emailid) on a new line. Save the resulting string into a file.

Then when reading, read the whole file into a string, split it by newline and you get all the items. For each line (item), split it using a semicolon and you get the 4 fields, you can cast them to the required types.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Silverlight Serializer from http://whydoidoit.com/ and just serialize the object to isolated storage. Its a really good serializer - its fast and its files are small. The code used to save and retrieve is

```
public static void SaveFile(string filename, object serializableObject, Type type)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile userStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (userStore.FileExists(filename))
            {
                userStore.DeleteFile(filename);
            }

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = userStore.CreateFile(filename))
            {
                SilverlightSerializer.Serialize(serializableObject, stream);
            }
        }
    }

    public static object LoadSerializedObjectFromFile(string filename, Type type)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile userStore =
          IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (userStore.FileExists(filename))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = userStore.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    return SilverlightSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I usually wrap the individual files in a repository (pattern). For instance in my Good Deal app, I have a DealRepository.  In that repository I have a static Load method like shown here:

```
 private static IDeal LoadRecentDeal()
    {
        IDeal savedDeals = IsolatedStorageHelper.LoadSerializedObjectFromFile(RecentDealFileName, typeof(Deal)) as Deal;
        if (savedDeals != null)
        {
            return savedDeals;
        }
        else
        {
            return Deal.CreateNewDeal(RecentDealFileName);
        }
    }
```

The inner save method is something like this:

```
public void Save(IDeal deal)
    {
        deal.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

        // 
        string fileName;
        if (deal.Name == RecentDealFileName)
        {
            fileName = RecentDealFileName;
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = SavedDirectoryName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + deal.ID.ToString();
        }

        IsolatedStorageHelper.SaveFile(fileName, deal, typeof(IDeal));       
    }
```

And there are several other methods on the IsolatedStorageHelper and repositories used to do things like save a list of in multiple files and return them ... etc.  All depends on your needs - but I would recommend checking out the Silverlight Serializer, it makes it pretty simple.